# Sound: Debian 9 only detects headphone or speaker

Tags: debian, alsa

I recently installed Debian 9 on my computer, and I noticed that the audio peripherals weren't well detected.
If my headphones are plugged in through the front panel audio, the speakers(plugged on the motherboard jack) are not detected.

In Windows it worked well, and I could swap between audio outputs without unplugging and plugging back my headphones, so this is a purely software issue, but it's very annoying.

Can somebody help with this issue ?
Thanks.